# Converting a DeWalt charger from 110V to 220V, rational of component selection from the guide

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

I'm going to convert my DeWalt charger from 110V to 240V as I got sick of lugging a step converter around.

I have found two guides which use the exact model of charger I have but they have partly different solution. I would like to know more of what could be the reason that they did what they did.

It is clear that the transformer that powers the charging circuit can handle 240V. Both of the guides replaced the 200V 220uF which I totally understand - that capacitor would pop under 240 VAC and should be replaced with a value above the peak 400V + should be fine.

Now the similarities end, the [first guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rc5ieIGUYBo) changed the capacitor and added 2  0.33Ohm  5W resistors.

[image]

The [second guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DJRJk5MQrU) did not speak in english so I did not understand what he was saying but basically I think he add a varistor on the main input and instead of using a resistor I'm not sure what that black thing is (ceramic capacitor?) but why would he add a capacitor? If you closely look on either of the videos you might notice that that slot is labeled "R" so I assume a resistor is supposed to be placed there (instead of a jumper.)

[image]

Can someone help explain to me what could they possibly be doing? Sadly I don't currently have my charger so I can't take more detailed pictures of the circuit. But maybe someone may have an idea based on past experience.

Comment: It would be significantly more time and cost effective to purchase a compatible adapter locally even if it is not brand name. you risk breaking your only charger permanently, despite the inconvenience your current system works, rework has non zero probability of failure

Comment: The resistors limit inrush current to the input cap(s).  The black disk is most likely a PTC thermistor or polyfuse type of device.  It functions similar to the resistors, but is intended to have lower loses, as its resistance is lower when cool, but increases when hot, which happens during high currents like during inrush.

Comment: @crasic no worries i have 3 of them, at first ill do 1, observe for 1 or 2 months, if its still good then ill be converting the others

Comment: @crasic That's up to the asker to decide

Comment: @Aaron how about the first one whats up with 2 high power resistors?

Comment: The resistors limit inrush current to the input cap(s).

Comment: Oh, and the red disk is a MOV.  It's designed to protect against input voltage transients. I'd be careful with that one, it should have a thermal fuse or something to open if it starts to cook off.

Comment: @Aaron,  yes from what i know MOV are basically a short when they exceed their rating. Im thinking i can get away not placing that one. As for that varistor and resistor which would be ideally be better?

Comment: Are you sure the charger is not wide-range to start with? I'm not talking about the range stamped on the type plate, but the actual charger. I've seen on multiple occasions a 85-264 VAC product having 100-120 V on the nameplate for the US and Japanese market and 220-240 V for the rest of the world. EDIT: does yours have a single 200 V DC cap on the primary side?

Comment: @Winny definitely not  for 240 VAC out of the box, one of workers accidentally  plugged the charger on a 240 outlet instead of the step-down, blown the capacitor, I replaced it with a similar one and still works fine to this day, And wouldn't you know it that capacitor is the one being replaced by both guides

Comment: @winny i could not confirm with MY actuall charger since it not with me currently. But i have the same model as both in the guides (same with the pictures). So yes, there is a very high posibility that i have a single 200v DC cap on the primary

Comment: Oh! Then we know what we are dealing with. If they took the effort to create two versions at all, it's unlikely it's just the input capacitor. You can check the voltage rating on the primary side MOSFET but even if it's say 700 V, it's hard to tell if they are using different transformers or not. How much is a second hand 230 V charger?

Comment: It is quite risky to do this without having an idea of electrical margins on all the components. Usually, the main MOSFET is rated for 500 V in a single mains input like a 110 V version which translates in a 155-V bus (200-V capacitors). Go to 230 V rms and you end-up having 330 V across these capacitors (400 V types are necessary). The MOSFET needs to be a 600/650-V type. Then, the output diodes may not survive the extra stress as the voltage at the anode will swing more negative than before. Finally, the peak current in the transformer may be much higher considering the possible overshoot.

Comment: @VerbalKint The second guide showed this mosfet [TK12A60W](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/mosfets/400v-900v-mosfets/detail.TK12A60W.html) which likely to be the one (not sure since he is speaking a language foreign to me ) and as you said its a 600V mosfet

Comment: What im thinking is happening here they basically made 1 board for both 110 an 220 version with designing in mind for tthe 220  and making it so to have as little difference with the 110 to save cost in production

Comment: Sure, but if you have BOM variants for the same PCB, that may as well include two different transformers. It's pretty much down to how the bean counters at DeWalts parent company reasons around these things. 600 V transistor rating is borderline between 110 and 230 V depending on technology. Is it forward or flyback?

Comment: @winny the second guide [showed a glimps](https://ibb.co/JnBr83V) of the transformer part number currently looking a datasheet for it

Comment: You won't find the data-sheet, it is probably Phihong who manufactured the board and they use their own magnetics. A 600-V MOSFET looks fine providing there is enough margin but it's risky for the sec-side diodes: what part-number are these? Can you measure the neg. voltage at the anode when supplied from a 110-V input? If yes, you can check the margin if you multiply this voltage by two when going to 230 V.

Comment: @VerbalKint i do not have the chargers at the moment i will have to follow up the answer to that tomorrow.

Comment: I got into a rabbit hole going to russian forums and apparently 220-110 conver that looks like [this](http://www.78294.ru/forum/16-36-1) exist which are definitly better than the transformers im using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the comments already. A risky business and can cause bigger damage than you expect. Think about a fire when you are sleeping. Without a schematic and proper research its detailed operation it's impossible to decide how near to blow the charger really is after making those changes.

I have seen chargers that operate as well with 110V and 240V and both 50 and 60Hz. They are designed for that range. Larger margins require more complex design and higher cost parts. It's very difficult to believe that mass produced equipment suppliers want to carry that extra cost overburden.

Where I live modifications like this would be considered criminal, because there still reads all original supplier's texts and the device is changed to other. In addition only a contractor who has the licence determined by the regulation code can legally make works which change the structure of mains AC operated equipment.

Not asked: The white glue mass is essential to keep the device at least some time as one piece when it's transported in a toolbox in a car. Soldering joints alone will not stand vibrations of big parts. The ceramic resistors need it as well as the capacitor.

Comment: I do thank every one for giving their opinions,  i have since abandoned of doing this, because as you said the risk is not worth it. I mean there are 240v version available of the chargers, its just US marketing saying its 20v "max" battery and really just have the same number of battery (5) on the 18v counterpart. the 18v battery will also reach 20v on a full charge.

Comment: That is just another comment, it's not an answer. As long as you don't show any partical advice on to convert the device to 220v as the author asked, you do not belong this section. You can easily fit the comments and if it's important enough you'll get enough likes to get attention

Comment: The questioner seemed to ask how rational the presented modificationa are. Clicking the green checkmark was possible to be undone if it was an accident.